# How to capture a function's environment instead of its return value

Tags: r, function, environment-variables

Given a function creating several objects in its temporary environment:

```
myFun <- function(arg1 = "hey", arg2 = "bye") {
     x <- paste(arg1, arg2)
     y <- paste(x, "hey")
     z <- paste(y, "again!")
     
     return(z)
}
```

Is there a function that can extract the temporary environment of another function ?
e.g.

```
myFun_env <- capture_env(myFun())
```

That would return as output the equivalent to:

```
myFun_env <- rlang::env(
     arg1 = "hey",
     arg2 = "bye",
     x = paste(arg1, arg2),
     y = paste(x, "hey"),
     z = paste(y, "again!")
 )
```

```
> rlang::env_print(myFun_env)
<environment: 0x556959d73708>
parent: <environment: global>
bindings:
 * x: <chr>
 * y: <chr>
 * z: <chr>
 * arg1: <chr>
 * arg2: <chr>
```

**Update 1:**
Solution from user G. Grothendieck https://stackoverflow.com/users/516548/g-grothendieck

```
> trace(myFun, quote(assign(".Env", environment(), .GlobalEnv)), print = FALSE)
> myFun()
> rlang::env_print(.Env)
<environment: 0x556bf1a8ec08>
parent: <environment: global>
bindings:
 * z: <chr>
 * y: <chr>
 * x: <chr>
 * arg1: <chr>
 * arg2: <chr>
> .Env$arg1
[1] "hey"
```

This modifies the function's body, but can be removed via untrace:

```
> body(myFun)
{
    .doTrace(assign(".Env", environment(), .GlobalEnv))
    {
        x <- paste(arg1, arg2)
        y <- paste(x, "hey")
        z <- paste(y, "again!")
        return(z)
    }
}
> untrace(myFun)
> body(myFun)
{
    x <- paste(arg1, arg2)
    y <- paste(x, "hey")
    z <- paste(y, "again!")
    return(z)
}

>
```

**Update 2:**
Wrapping things up, we could have a function that captures another function's environment, returns it and writes it to disk for further loading:

```
captureAndSave_functionEnv <- function (myFun, ...) {
  
  trace(myFun, quote(assign(".myFun_env", environment(), .GlobalEnv)), print = FALSE)
  #trace(myFun, quote({ untrace(myFun); assign(".myFun_env", environment(), parent.frame()) }), print = FALSE)
  on.exit(untrace(myFun))
  
  myFun(...)
  
  saveRDS(.myFun_env, paste0(deparse(substitute(myFun)), ".rds"))
  
  return(.myFun_env)
}
```

```
> captureAndSave_functionEnv(myFun)
<environment: 0x558f877eff20>
> myFun_env_loaded <- readRDS("myFun.rds")
> rlang::env_print(myFun_env_loaded)
<environment: 0x558f86d00890>
parent: <environment: global>
bindings:
 * z: <chr>
 * y: <chr>
 * x: <chr>
 * arg1: <chr>
 * arg2: <chr>
> myFun_env_loaded$arg1
[1] "hey"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use trace to inject a statement that captures the environment as a side effect:

```
trace(myFun, quote(assign(".Env", environment(), .GlobalEnv)), print = FALSE)

myFun()
## [1] "hey bye hey again!"

ls(.Env)
## [1] "arg1" "arg2" "x"    "y"    "z"
```

Comment: I think that does it, then we do not need to change the function's definition. 
This is dark magic to me however haha.

Comment: It actually does change the function definition. Try body(myFun)

Comment: oh indeed, but we can use untrace to revert it ?
So maybe we can have a function that does the `trace...` and then `on.exit` we do an `untrace(myFun)`

Comment: This would untrace it at the first run: `trace(myFun, quote({ untrace(myFun); assign(".Env", environment(), .GlobalEnv) }), print = FALSE)`

Answer (score 2):

After the function is called, the function’s call environment (its “stack frame”) no longer exists, unless the lifetime of that frame was somehow extended, by being referenced from somewhere.<sup>1</sup>

So, no, there’s no way to get the environment after the fact from outside. What you *can* do is modify the function:

```
myFun <- function(arg1 = "hey", arg2 = "bye") {
     x <- paste(arg1, arg2)
     y <- paste(x, "hey")
     z <- paste(y, "again!")

     environment()
}
```

Here we return the call frame instead of `z`.

---

<sup>1</sup> If this isn’t done explicitly, the environment is generally not referenced anywhere. However, there are exceptions: both *functions* and *formulas* by default reference the environment they were defined in. As a consequence, if you define a function or formula inside `myFun()` and return that, you *can* retrieve the call frame of a `myFun(…)` invocation by calling `environment()` on the return value.

Comment: Ah yes indeed, maybe we can change the body of "myFun" in place via a functional ?
So that we don't need to have environment() within the function definition, but add this to the body only in this case.

Comment: @StephGC True, I guess: you could replace `body(f)` with `bquote({.(body(f)); environment()})`.

Comment: The context is to have an easy way to store each intermediate objects to build unit tests on each functions (well here it would be paste).
It could be done by adding in the function e.g.:
```
 if (saveOutputForTests) {
    saveRDS(ls(all.names = TRUE), file = paste0(deparse(sys.calls()[[sys.nframe()-1]]), "_environment.rds"))
  }
  ```
But then it needs to be added to each functions for which we want to capture the environment.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, call the `environment` function inside your function.

```r
f <- function()
{
    x <- 42
    environment()
}
```

```
r$> f()
<environment: 0x0000020a1302a5a8>
r$> f()$x
[1] 42
```